# What is a single word for both location and size of an object?

Tags: single-word-requests

An object has a location (or center) (x, y, z) and a size (or dimensions) (width, height, length).

What is a single word for both? I thought of "measurements" but it's not so accurate.

Comment: The linked answer is not a duplicate as that question requests a word for something that is moveable and resizeable - (the answer given was "adjustable") -  it does not address a word that offers a location and includes the item's dimensions.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Don't know what to do. If I ask a new question they will close it as duplicate.

Comment: user3737190: Is there a word for it in your language? Can you give an example sentence (using "X" for your word) which would demonstrate how the word would be used?